# Conversion between String and Stanford NLP Word

Tags: stanford-nlp, stemming

I am trying to do stemming using the Stanford Core NLP's Stemmer class (https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/Stemmer.java).

I am trying to call the stemmer method(which I edited a little) from another class as shown below, note that `term` is a string :

```
String stemmedterm=CoreNLPKeyPhraseStemmer.keystemming(term);
```

The main work of stemming in the CoreNLPKeyPhraseStemmer's `keystemming` method is done by the following line:

```
String s1= s.stem(token.word());
```

However, my problem is that the type of `token` must be `Word` i.e.edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Word (https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/index.html?edu/stanford/nlp/ling/Word.html) while I am supplying String while calling `keystemming` from the other class. Is there any way to convert the supplied String to `Word`?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code for the `Word` class, it seems to support `String` in its constructor so I believe you just have to do

```
Word(token.stem())
```

To get a word object for the stemmed token.